# Multiple checks with if else and or in yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to utilize one YAML file for multiple environments with different configuration settings.

Below is the yaml example:

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: Build Environment
  type: string
  default: Staging
  values:
  - Staging
  - Release
  - Production

variables: 
  - name: certificatename
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'Staging') }}:
  value: 'cert1.p12'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'Release') }}:
  value: 'cert2.p12'
```

Is there a way to club release and prod in one go?

like `${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'Release'), eq(parameters.environment, 'Production') }}:`
however, I keep getting errors. If anyone knows of any way to the club this statement, would appreciate the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `in` operator instead of `eq` to check for multiple values

```
${{ if in(parameters.environment, 'Release', 'Production') }}:
```

documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#in

[image]